# Keyset as registered is invalid exception when Importing a RSA Key Container using aspnet_regiis

Tags: rsa, aspnet-regiis.exe

I have been trying to import a RSA key container from aspnet_regiis. Steps are as follows.

1. Run the command prompt as administrator
2. cd C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
3. aspnet_regiis -pi myrsakey E:\keyfile.xml

When followed the above steps I get the error as follows

**

> Importing RSA Keys from file.. Keyset as registered is invalid.
> <Exception from HRESULT: 0x8009001A> Failed!

**

For this "Keyset as registered is invalid" error almost every web result says to try renaming RSA file in the path C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto to RSA.old and reboot. If that does not work try renaming Crypto folder as Crypto.old. Eventhough I tried these steps it did not resolve the above issue. I am even running the cmd as administrator. So I was not sure what I am missing in here. Would you be help me to find a solution or a workaround for this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the answer.

As I was installing this RSA as a machine level key I should have renamed the RSA to RSA.old in the path C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto

After rename and I reboot the system. And then did the above mentioned steps again in the cmd. This time it succeded.

Previously I was renaming the RSA folder in the wrong place which is in my personal area (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto).